# What is faster, normal functions or OOP singleton patterns

Tags: php, function, oop, design-patterns, singleton

When I started programing my motivation was to get the result and the speed was not so important for me, but by time I understood that the speed is very important.

I don't think that between normal functions and OOP singleton patters is a big difference when it comes about performance, but anyway I'd like to know which one is faster.

So which is faster?

This:

```
my_prefix_fn_name($arg1, $arg2);
my_prefix_fn_name2($arg1, $arg2);
```

or this:

```
Class_Name::fn_name($arg1, $arg2);
Class_Name::fn_name2($arg1, $arg2);
```

or this:

```
$cname = 'Class_Name';
$cname::fn_name($arg1, $arg2);
$cname::fn_name2($arg1, $arg2);
```

Comment: assuming static methods, you'll probably find little or NO difference in speeds.

Comment: Between the first and second options the difference in time will no nothing or right next to it. The third option would require a little more overhead and shouldn't be used unless there is a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Go back to thinking that result is more important. Unless you are expecting a huge amount of traffic, these kind of micro-optimizations will make no difference. Concentrate on making sure your code is clear and easy to understand.

Comment: You'll find that the Singleton pattern is **bad practice**. It's basically global state, which makes testing hard. The same goes with static methods. If you don't want to have more than one object at once, then just don't instantiate another instance of one. If you can't help but instantiate another instance of one, then it looks like you need to refactor and take a look at your application architecture.

Comment: if you´re so concerned about speed to deal with this, you shouldn´t be using PHP in the first place.

Comment: @DanyCaissy, I always try to make the code clear as much as possible. I've created a PHP class with all form elements I need, and call it anywhere I need, this make my life easier, because I use just one code base. I like the OOP approach, more than normal functions.

Comment: The slow part is not calling the function but when php initialises it into memory, im pretty sure an object is slower then a bunch of global functions on initialisation but its a micro second trade of for a better quality of code.

Comment: @hynner, I'm not concerned about the speed regarding this example. It's just the curiosity. Don't tell me that you're a PHP hater. :P

Comment: @Smartik , FYI: singletons are not part of OOP paradigm. Neither are the static methods in general.

Comment: @tereško, when I say OOP I'm not refering to this example, but to a general point of view. I make my application and get parts from it when I need them, using singleton patterns. ;) I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't measured it myself but based on experience I have a feeling the normal functions are faster than static functions because they normal one is stored underneath the parent, vs being nested.

But anyway the point in this answer was to share this link: http://phpperf.com/ (and I don't know how to write comments yet). But it gives you a few examples of some built in function speeds.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the best answer so far. Thanks for this link.

Answer (score 0):

Measure it yourself!

And remember that whatever you measure will most likely be only a little different. Execution speed is not the only thing that counts. Readability of the code is way more important, because changing the code usually costs orders of magnitude more than executing it.

And please remember to not implement singletons! They are an antipattern. I won't go into details on this here.

Comment: (And static methods). **Measure Yourself!**

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried running a benchmark test on these to determine the millisecond or even nanosecond run time differences between example 1 and example 2?

Basic benchmark test

```
[Get datetime for start timestamp]
    [For Loop, run 1000 times]
        [Run Function, example 1 or 2]
    [End For]
[Get datetime for end timestamp]

[Print time difference in milliseconds between end and start times]
```

Then compare. I don't expect there to be much difference if any. Although I expect the 3rd example to have  a slightly worse performance but all is negligible. It is all about maintainability of your code and time spent to make future enhancements, not really squeezing out very marginal performance gains that couldn't be detected by the naked eye.

Comment: I did such test before and is no difference. To see the difference I must run the code at least 10000 times not 1000. ;)

Comment: First, these benchmarks actually are worth doing if you are not sure of the impact of your code practices and if you had to run 10,000 to recognize ANY difference then it seems to me you had your answer.